# Selenium does not work when we get a upgrade from firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, behat, mink

I am working on Automation tool Behat/Mink . After upgrading Firefox version to 25 , i am seeing this error .

```
     Curl error thrown for http POST to http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/execute with params: {"script":"return document.getElementById('user') !== null;","args":[]}      
  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1: Can't assign requested address
```

I am using selenium webdriver version 2.37.0.jar as the server.

Answer (score 0):

Support for Firefox 25 has been added in version 2.38. Current version is 2.39 which supports Firefox 26. 
It is a good practice to check for the new selenium version every time Firefox upgrades. Updating the server should work.

[Official download page](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Comment: ok , i have tried with 2.38 . But still it shows this error .Curl error thrown for http DELETE to http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session    
                                                                               
  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1: Can't assign requested address

Answer (score -1):

run this command before running your tests

```
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-*
```

this will help you to resolve your problem

make sure your selenium latest version should be on same folder